# I Took a Word to Work with Me #1

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, humor

I took a word to work with me
And it made me look quite stately
Then afterwards, I had some tea
Which improved my grunge look greatly
But my caffeine brain got jumbled up
And I was gasping to have some more
I rushed to the kettle,
The middle fell out
My brain got in a pickle,
And I nearly went lying to death's door

---

What's the word?

---

Hints

> 1. What's a grunge look?

Comment: rot13(Vf gur svefg cnentencu nalguvat gb qb jvgu Aveinan?)

Comment: @Deolus, no it's not. Any reference is purely coincidental!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I thought I might have it, I started strongly but then got a bit lost. Thought I would post a partial answer here though, in case it inspires someone.

Could the word be:

> Shirt

I took a word to work with me
And it made me look quite stately

> Wearing a collared shirt to work adds dignity

Then afterwards, I had some tea
Which improved my grunge look greatly

> Adding T (Tea) to shirt = T-Shirt, a more grunge look. Bonus points if it includes the Nirvana, Alice in Chains, Soundgarden or Pearl Jam logo.

But my caffeine brain got jumbled up
And I was gasping to have some more

> Jumbled hints to an anagram, which can give us "Thirst", which fits "gasping to have some more"

I rushed to the kettle,
The middle fell out

My brain got in a pickle,
And I nearly went lying to death's door

> The middle is falling out of my answer a bit - this is where I got lost.
>
>  The best I could do was:
>
>  The middle of 'kettle' is 'tt' and if we remove the two Ts from thirst we get "hirs"
>  Not exactly a word, but it sounds a lot like "Hearse" which could take us to deaths door!
>
>  Well, not really, because if you're in a hearse you have usually passed already through deaths door.

Comment: Wahey - well done!

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not correct, but I want to see if I am on the right track.

Is the word

> crown?

And it made me look quite stately

> a crown looks quite stately

The middle fell out... And I nearly went lying to death's door

> Removing the middle letters from crown yields CN which could be the -cyano group, responsible for forming highly toxic chemical compounds

Comment: You not on the right track sadly, although interesting approach (I'm not a chemist)! There are two transformations between your two explanations, so the words are not identical