# I took a Word to Work with Me #2

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, humor

I took a word to work with me
And it made me feel quite retentive,
Then when lunch came, my friends would agree,
Rearranging it was quite an incentive

Come home time and I reversed direction
To get me to my abode,
But my ire was combined
As I was hit from behind
And damaged my lymph node

---

What's the word?

---

**Hints**

> 1. These puzzles are based around word structure, and don't necessarily hold much meaning. Think anagrams, taking letters on or off etc.

Comment: I am assuming that the second stanza is somehow related to the first?

Comment: Yep, they both relate to "the word"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Piggybacking off kscherrer... maybe it is this?

> USB
>  quite retentive: USB (took to work)
>  lunch came: SUB (rearrange)
>  reversed direction: BUS (reversed)
>  damaged my lymph node: BRUISE (combine IRE)

Comment: Well done amoszoellner and kscherrer - I'd mark this as a joint effort if I could

Comment: If you like this sort of thing, I've made another puzzle previously - https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/100616/i-took-a-word-to-work-with-me-1

Answer (score 3):

Is the word...

> bus?

> I took a word to work with me
> And it made me feel quite retentive,

> you took the bus to go to work. You are now maybe retentive because you may have contracted a certain virus and don't want to be around coworkers.

> Then when lunch came, my friends would agree,
> Rearranging it was quite an incentive

> rearranging the letters of bus gives you a sub (as in "submarine sandwich"), perfect for lunch time!

> Come home time and I reversed direction,
> To get me to my abode,

> reverse 'sub' again to have a 'bus' to get you home.

> But my ire was combined
> As I was hit from behind
> And damaged my lymph node

> combining 'ire' with 'bus' gives us an 'airbus' (more or less), which hits you from behind apparently. Morale of the story: don't take the bus that takes its route through your local airport.

Comment: Agh - so close! Retentive means you are good at absorbing and retaining information, so perhaps try rejigging the word around. The second and third answers are correct, but I can't allow ROT17(ziv reu slj zj rzislj - zk'j zivslj!). Please see the new hint I've added

Comment: If you enjoy solving this sort of thing, I've made one previously - https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/100616/i-took-a-word-to-work-with-me-1

Comment: Ha, and I thought I was doing just a fun answer. I still dont understand the retentive part, but thats okay (not main language). I'm glad I helped find the solution

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a stretch but was it

> chips?

And it made me feel quite retentive

> Chips have a lot of salt which make you feel bloated or retentive (of water)

Rearranging it was quite an incentive

> When you reach in a bag of chips to eat them, you rearrange the chips inside

And damaged my lymph node

> If you eat a lot of salt, your lymph nodes swell... making it more likely that you would damage lymph nodes in your neck (or anywhere in your body) if you experience impact from being rear ended

Comment: I'm sorry, this is not quite correct - very creative though! The fact that the lymph node was damaged has nothing to do with it's function (pure coincidence). Also, your answer does not fit the third stanza - you can't use "them" to get home!